# About output of this loop program

Tags: java, loops, increment

The output of this program this is: iiiii .
  and this is because of i++ used after  print statement. ++ means increment and  without i++ its printing i  10 times .then how  it will give this output iiiii .it has to be increment one more

```
  class array_output {

            public static void main(String args[]) 

            {    

                char array_variable [] = new char[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

                    array_variable[i] = 'i';

                    System.out.print(array_variable[i] + "" );

                    i++;

                }

            } 

        }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an expected output as you are incrementing the i twice. simple solution is to remove last line in the for loop.

output from your program:

> i = 0
>
> i = 2
>
> i = 4
>
> i = 6
>
> i = 8
>
> i = 10

After removing the last increment

iiiiiiiiii

Your code should be

```
 class array_output {

        public static void main(String args[]) 

        {    

            char array_variable [] = new char[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

                array_variable[i] = 'i';

                System.out.print(array_variable[i] + "" );

               // i++; // you are incrementing i again. No need to do if you want  a jump of 1 step.

            }

        } 

    }
```

> Ok. After reading again here is the answer for the question. When you enter forloop for the first time your ***i*** is ***0*** and after entering you said ***i++*** which will be ***1*** and then ***++i*** which becomes ***2*** so for every i you are making a jump of ***2 steps*** so that's the reason after ***5 iterations*** you are reaching 10 and your ***for loop*** condition ***i<10*** fails. So, the loop further won't execute and exit successfully.
>
> Sorry for the wrong output in my previous answer. Here is the right output. .

```
 i = 0  

 i = 2 

 i = 4 

 i = 6 

 i = 8
```

Comment: i got your point .but why it first enter to i++ and then ++i.and why not enter in ++i first and then i++..to incriment

Comment: Vikas, i am not clear about your comment. Can you please elaborate or explain more on your comment.